# Почему в PGAdmin4 не отображаются записи таблицы?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql, flask

Я зашел в PGAdmin4. INSERT'ом вставил туда 4 записи, 1 из которых содержала русский текст, а затем вышел. А когда я зашел в следующий раз, то при попытке посмотреть записи, вылезло зеленое окошко, с уведомлением, что имеется 4 записи в таблице, но они не отображаются. Я добавил еще одну, она отобразилась. А других так и нет. И всего их теперь 5! Как посмотреть остальные, куда они пропали?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зеленое окошко показывает результат выполнения запроса, а сколько записей в таблице зависит от количества завершенных транзакций. Возможно Вы выполняли комманды с включенной опцией autocommit(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы видите "Зеленое окошко" которое показывает результат выполнения запроса `SELECT` он запрашивает содержимое таблицы и заполняет GRID. Так как вы не привели запроса на `INSERT` можно предположить что вы редактировали данные в GRID добавиви в него строки. Нужно понимать что содержимое таблицы GRID никак не связано с фактическим содержимым таблицы в самой базе и реализует идеологию отключенных не блокирующих наборов данных. Что бы применить изменения данных к таблице в базе нужно нажать кнопку `F6` это приведет к попытке внести изменения выполненные в отключенном наборе в таблицу базы данных и если за время вашей работы таблица не претерпела критических изменений конфликтующих с вашими (например измененная вами строка была кем то удалена) изменения вступят в силу в таблице базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятней всего, для отображения данных после совершения транзакции insert, необходимо выполнить `commit`.
Инструкция `commit` гарантирует, что все изменения в пределах данной транзакции стали постоянной частью базы данных.
Конструкция sql выглядит следующим образом:
`insert into ... ;` `commit;`

Comment: В базу всё занеслось, только хочет отображать. В предыдущий раз всё было нормально. А сейчас только "5 rows affected" справа снизу, а по факту 1.